# can't fetch data into a list in flutter using firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to fetch data from firebase cloud firestore in flutter, but i'm struggling to save it into a specific list.

Here is my code:

```
Future<List<Intervention>> fetchInterventions() async {
      List<Intervention> ivs = [];
      final doc =
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('interventions').get();
      final interventionsTmp = doc.data();
      interventionsTmp .forEach((interventionTmp ) {
        ivs.add(Intervention.fromJson(interventionTmp ));
      });
      return ivs;
    }
```

and here is my model:

```
class Intervention {
  final String intervention;
  final String dateIv;
  final String etat;
  final int prix;
  final String numero;

  Intervention(
      {required this.dateIv,
      required this.etat,
      required this.numero,
      required this.intervention,
      required this.prix});

  static Intervention fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Intervention(
        dateIv: map['date_iv'],
        etat: map['etat'],
        intervention: map['intervention'],
        numero: map['numIntervention'],
        prix: map['prix']);
  }
}
```

For now the problem is that I cannot access the data in this line final `interventionsTmp = doc.data();` since `data()` isn't a known method for it! I'm stuck at accessing the data.

I tried several solutions but couldn't solve it, I'd be glad with any kind of help.

Comment: You need to show some error code or the issue this is causing when you are trying to add?

Comment: The problem is you are not converting the data in the snapshot to the List

Comment: Exactly, and I couldn't find a way to convert it into a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `fetchInterventions` to this:

```
Future<List<Intervention>> fetchInterventions() async {
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('interventions').get();
  
  
  return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => Intervention.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList();;
}
```

Comment: It says that the method .map() isn't defined for docs as it's a QuerySnapshot object!

Comment: It's now pointing out the following error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>' on doc.data().

Comment: I updated my answer again try cast doc.data() to Map<String, dynamic>. @FedyBelaid

Comment: Alright it's now giving me a list of Instance of 'Intervention', I think the problem is solved! Thank you for your answer!